# PrimeFaces UIMenuItem objects get invalid IDs

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm currently working on a task that involves updating a project's PrimeFaces library from PrimeFaces 3.2 to 6.0.

From version 3.5 to 4.0 there was a [API change in PrimeFaces' MenuModel](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide) that is not backwards compatible.

The code I'm dealing with makes use of the class `org.primefaces.component.menuitem.MenuItem` which extends `javax.faces.component.UICommand`.

From PrimeFaces 4.0 onward, `org.primefaces.component.menuitem.MenuItem` is an interface and there is a new class `org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem` that implements that interface and also extends `javax.faces.component.UICommand`. The new `UIMenuItem` class has more or less the same interface as the old `MenuItem` class, at least it supports all methods that are used in the code I'm dealing with.

So obviously I changed the insantiation code for `MenuItem` objects to make use of the new `UIMenuItem` class. Doing that, the code compiles without errors, but it fails at runtime with this exception:

```
Dec 01, 2016 11:58:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.validateId(UIComponentBase.java:542)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setId(UIComponentBase.java:363)
```

In the debugger I can see that there are in fact `UIMenuItem` objects with an id of `0` hanging around.

The `UIMenuItem` objects are all created by a factory method that looks like this:

```
public static MenuItem createNavigationMenuItem() {
    UIMenuItem item = new UIMenuItem();
    item.setStyle("padding: 0;");
    item.setUpdate(":tableForm,:navForm");
    item.addActionListener(actionListener);
    return item;
}
```

Here's the thing now. The ids of those `UIMenuItem` objects get set by this code in [`org.primefaces.model.menu.BaseMenuModel`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/f6a0e54f4d11470bad319c6d21fd27f411015706/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/menu/BaseMenuModel.java):

```
public void generateUniqueIds() {
    this.generateUniqueIds(getElements(), null);
}

private void generateUniqueIds(List<MenuElement> elements, String seed) {
    if(elements == null || elements.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    int counter = 0;

    for(MenuElement element : elements) {
        String id = (seed == null) ? String.valueOf(counter++) : seed + ID_SEPARATOR + counter++;
        element.setId(id);

        if(element instanceof MenuGroup) {                
            generateUniqueIds(((MenuGroup) element).getElements(), id);
        }
    }
}
```

I read this code like this: When `generateUniqueIds()` gets called, The MenuElements referenced by the `elements` parameter will inevitably get ids of `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

Now please have a look at this method in `javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase`:

```
private static void validateId(String id) {

    if (id == null) {
        return;
    }
    int n = id.length();
    if (n < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty id attribute is not allowed");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char c = id.charAt(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(c) && (c != '_')) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(id);
            }
        } else {
            if (!Character.isLetter(c) &&
                    !Character.isDigit(c) &&
                    (c != '-') && (c != '_')) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As it can clearly be seen, ids starting with a digit will always cause an `IllegalArgumentException` and that is exactly where my code fails!

Now I'm wondering: why is there code in a PrimeFaces library that gives obviously invalid (according to the JSF code it is building upon) ids to `MenuElement` objects?

Following the [First Rule of Programming](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/), I'm sure that the PrimeFaces code is fine and my puzzlement is founded in a lack of understanding on my side. But still, that code in `BaseMenuModel` makes no sense to me. Is there anybody who could help me figure out what it is that I'm not getting?

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but I think you should create 'DefaultMenuItem'

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, thanks for your comment! The thing is, the code I'm dealing with calls `getAttributes()` on the `MenuItem` which `UIMenuItem` inherits by extending `UICommand` but `DefaultMenuItem` does not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot mixe MenuModel with UIMenuItems: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/199

Comment: Bad reference to an issue: Title is "p:link does not consider f:param tag"